# Can I update values from within ElasticSearch native script plugin?

Tags: plugins, elasticsearch, native

I'm writing a naive plugin for ElasticSearch and I would much like to update a field from within this script. Is there a way?

Context: I'm trying to use ELK stack to chart differences between documents. The documents are produced from two separate sources continuously. 
I have sorted all the pieces, but this one is the last mile for me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I figured it'll need a org.elasticsearch.client.Client within Plugin code. Thanks all.

Comment: Hi @bhoo-day, sorry for the delay, just spotted this comment. 
It's been a while so the information is fuzzy in my head but I remember I didn't go the plugin way, instead got Logstash to work suitably by using UPSERT command. There are a lot of examples on Upsert on the web, if you'd like what I did, let me know and I'll post it to you :).